# Methods for Cost Analysis in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following spreadsheet:
[Cost Analysis Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19n_UH2fJxomur13G_I89WRaqW93KH6Z0FIpUOzsciyE/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to think of the best way to analyze the cost impact on a Variant based on the different components of the product.  I am having a very tough time trying to be creative and think of ways to identify cost trade-off analysis using Google Sheets.

Basically, I am trying to find methods within Sheets to help me visualize the added value of certain components for a Variant.

I know that this is difficult to do without any domain knowledge of the application, but I am hoping that someone has some more general ideas for how to do some reporting and visualization of data like this!

Thanks so much!

Comment: A question that is not self-contained (i.e. relies heavily on resources outside of the site to be understood) is of very limited use to future users. If you can [edit] this question to include the relevant information, _and to be an on-topic programming question_, it would be helpful. Without that, it's likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already added conditional formating, which I consider great for visual identification of tables, given that I don't think this model would be improved by a graph. First I would recommend changing the conditional formatting to gradual and having the green extreme be the maximum negative value of the Diff.-columns. Second, if you want the simplest visualization possible, you can do a rank-list.

This would work like a dashboard, presenting the variants with the information you want. Here is an example, which takes the PN-column of the row with the lowest Diff-value in the Variant 3-rows: `=index(G3:I16,match(vlookup(SMALL(I3:I16,1),I3:I16,1,false),I3:I16),1)`

You can then alter the rank and the offset, to get a list for the # best variants with the columns you want.

Hope that helps, for the visualization. For advice on organization, I believe Google Sheets-forum is less appropriate :)